# Database Corruption - object in sys.parameters does not have a matching row in sys.objects

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a strange db corruption.
I ran `dbcc check db` and the output is:

> Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=1) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=2) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=3) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=4) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=5) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=6) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=7) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=8) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Attribute (object_id=1096186) of row (object_id=1096186,parameter_id=9) in sys.parameters does not have a matching row (object_id=1096186) in sys.objects.
>   Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 2

Now that's just a sample.
I've tried to run:

```
DBCC CHECKDB ('xxx', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

with no help, I tried to determine which object is that and drop and recreate the object by using select object_name (1096186) and it returns 'null'.

I've tried to do way back and still no valid backup all backups have the same corruption.
What should I do ?

Comment: How did you try which object is giving you the error? SELECT Object_Name(1096186)?

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand the question.

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-the-dedicated-admin-connection-to-fix-msg-8992-corrupt-system-tables/ ? Was this database from SQL server 2000? What service pack you are on ?

Comment: Excuse me, what is the output of
"SELECT Object_Name(1096186)"
command?

Comment: the answer is NULL